# Mailing the html report of cucumber through jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, cucumber, cucumber-java

Using the Cucumber reports plugin, able to generate the reports successfully. But when these reports are mailed using the mail plugin, the report doesn't look good at all.

How to send the html report like the view in the mail.
Need to mail all the reports "overview-failures, overview-features, overview-steps, overview-tags, report-feature_features-publish-mediaLibrary-MediaLibrary-feature, report-tag_developement" from jenkins.

Using the pre-script using in

```
dref reportPath=build.getWorkspace().child("/home/nagarjuna/jenkin/Simplify360_UI/target/site/cucumber-reports/cucumber-html-reports/overview-failures.html")
msg.setContent(reportPath.readToString()."text/html")
```

Other files in the reports folder are, which includes supporting files to render the report

```
css
embeddings
fonts
images
js
overview-failures.html
overview-features.html
overview-steps.html
overview-tags.html
report-feature_features-publish-mediaLibrary-MediaLibrary-feature.html
report-tag_developement.html
```

Current mailed reports looks like
[image]

Comment: are you using gmail account?

Comment: @Murthi to send reports, yes. Any suggestions to improve this?

Comment: Gmail is blocking any javascript and css style in the emil. so that, formating is not working as expected. try to send it as attachement or host it in a server.

Comment: @Murthi don't think Gmail is an issue is here. As I'm not able to send the javascript, CSS files, the report is not readable. Updated question with the prescript being used in jenkins and other files in the reports folder.

Comment: Think your browser console offers help here. You'll see it cant find (or at least execute) the scripts that make the report look pretty.
The exact message might help here

Comment: @SirLenz0rlot I can see the report is sent successfully in the jenkins build console. I see error in `dref reportPath=build.getWorkspace().child("/home/nagarjuna/jenkin/Simplify360_UI/target/site/cucumber-reports/cucumber-html-reports/overview-failures.html")
` where I do not see an option to insert the css , fonts and other files.

Comment: mail != webserver. even if you'd attach the js/css files, gmail won't execute them. either:
1) zip the entire folder into an email;
2) just email a link to the report;
3) write a reporter that doesn't need js to render

Comment: @SirLenz0rlot any suggestions on the reporting

Comment: There 3 suggestions in my previous comment. I don't see many other options for this to work tbh.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1158354/nagarjuna-reddy- did you get a solution to this?